# Remove class on click and add to another element

Tags: jquery

I have a navigation menu and when 'contact is clicked' a div opens at the top of the DOM, I want to add an active state to contact using jQuery but for some reason cant get it working.

I'vbe made a fiddle to hopefully explain better...

http://jsfiddle.net/PFD5C/

Comment: There's a missing `});` at the end of the script.

Comment: Your fiddle was missing a `});` http://jsfiddle.net/PFD5C/3/

Comment: I can't see why this would open a div when Contact is clicked...

Comment: @bukko I think this is a truncated example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not closing your click handler. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Append class to contact
    $('.contact').click(function() {
        $("li a").removeClass("static");
        $(this).addClass("static");
    });
});​
```

[**Your updated fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/karim79/PFD5C/1/)

P.S. Hitting the "JSLint" button would have helped you to identify the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In your fiddle you missed a closing `});`

This is why properly indenting your code should be the first thing you learn when you start coding.

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/PFD5C/2/)

Answer (score 1):

In you're JS fiddle link, you didn't have the end brackets / parens / semicolon for the click event. This seemed to work for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Append class to contact
    $('.contact').click(function(){
        $("li a").removeClass("static");
        $(this).addClass("static");    
    });                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one closing brace

```
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't close your `.click()` object by adding an `});` at the end, you see this works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/PFD5C/5/